# mpeg-dash playback on ios and safari

Tags: ios, ffmpeg, safari, mpeg-dash

I have created some mpeg-dash videos using ffmpeg and mp4box. it is playing well on android and chrome browser, but not on ios and safari. as far as i know it should play on ios 10+ but its is not. can anyone help me with this?

Comment: Are you using an m3u8 manifest?

Comment: @szatmary no the manifest is mpd

Comment: iOS only plays HLS. Not dash. You may be able to use the same video files, but you at least need an m3u8.

Comment: could you explain more? do you have a link that can guide me? I don't know how to make the m3u8 manifest with my dash segments because the command I use for hls is different from the command I use for mpeg-dash. I have read that safari 10+ supports mpeg-dash, I tried the video on mac safari, and it plays the video well, but on iphone 6, safari can not play the mpeg-dash @szatmary

Comment: No, I can not guide you beyond saying what I already said. Safari mac works because it support MSE. Safari iOS does not. Everything you need is available on line. Did you look up the m3u8 format?

Comment: so there is no way to play mpd manifest on ios safari? @szatmary

Comment: No there is not

Comment: so if safari can not play mpeg-dash natively on ios, is there any extension on safari or a specific player that we can use on ios to play it? thank you so much for your answers, I'm realy stuck on this issue. @szatmary

Comment: Your stuck on this issues because you keep trying to do something that can be done. Just google the resources I presented and write an m3u8. Yes it will take time to learn something new.

Comment: ok, thanks @szatmary